# Control sound of individual apps from icon

Tags: unity, sound

It is possible to control the sound of individual applications by clicking on the sound icon, going to "Sound settings...", and clicking on "Applications" (see e.g. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-volume.html)). I use this functionality a lot and would like to make it even easier to access. I would like the sound of individual applications to be controlled from the sound icon (or if necessary a separate icon). Is this possible?

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-volume.html